# Convert $facet mongo query to Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, aggregation-framework, facet

This is my working query to get multiple counts using [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/).

```
db.getCollection('test-collection').aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "highGroup": [
      { "$match" : { "ConfidenceScore": { $gte:80, $lt:90 }}},
      { "$count": "high" },
    ],
    "mediumGroup": [
      { "$match" : {"ConfidenceScore": { $gte:60, $lt:80 }}},
      { "$count": "medium" }
    ],
    "lowGroup": [
      { "$match" : {"ConfidenceScore": { $gte:20, $lt:60 }}},
      { "$count": "low" }         
    ],
     "falseGroup": [
      { "$match" : {"ConfidenceScore": { $lt:20 }}},
      { "$count": "false" }
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "High": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$highGroup.high", 0] },
    "Medium": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$mediumGroup.medium", 0] },
    "Low": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$lowGroup.low", 0] },
    "False": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$falseGroup.false", 0], }
  }}
])
```

I am relatively new to Spring Data-

I have tried to convert the above query to Spring Data as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#_multi_faceted_aggregation) but it's throwing error as -

> the method match(criteria) is undefined

and wrt to $count I am not sure how to use it in Spring data $facet operation.
So far I have done this(which is incorrect) -

```
FacetOperation facet = facet(match(where("ConfidenceScore").gte(80).lt(90)), count().as("high")).as("highGroup"),
                    .and(match(where("ConfidenceScore").gte(60).lt(80)), count().as("medium")).as("mediumGroup"),
                    .and(match(where("ConfidenceScore").gte(20).lt(60)), count().as("low")).as("lowGroup"),
                    .and(match(where("ConfidenceScore").lt(20)), count().as("false")).as("falseGroup");

project()
      .and(ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt.arrayOf("highGroup").elementAt(0));
      .and(ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt.arrayOf("mediumGroup").elementAt(0));
      .and(ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt.arrayOf("lowGroup").elementAt(0));
      .and(ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt.arrayOf("falseGroup").elementAt(0));
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(facet); AggregationResults<FacetClassification> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, FacetClassification.class);
List<FacetClassification> facet = groupResults.getMappedResults();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code you tried in Spring?

Answer (score 2):

Inside `facet()`, can you try `match(Criteria.where(...))` instead of `match(where(...))`.

Your code would look like this:

```
FacetOperation facet = facet(match(Criteria.where("ConfidenceScore").gte(80).lt(90)), count().as("high")).as("highGroup"),
    .and(match(Criteria.where("ConfidenceScore").gte(60).lt(80)), count().as("medium")).as("mediumGroup"), 
    .and(match(Criteria.where("ConfidenceScore").gte(20).lt(60)), count().as("low")).as("lowGroup"), 
    .and(match(Criteria.where("ConfidenceScore").lt(20)), count().as("false"))
.as("falseGroup");
```

Comment: I updated the code as above, the error - "The method match(Criteria) is undefined for the type .." still exists.